# Router Link in VUE JS is not showing active

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I hope you are having an amazing week. The thing is I'm learning VUE for a couple of weeks now but currently I'm facing an issue with VUE Router. Following is the issue that I'm facing:

1- I have registered 5 routes and their corresponding views are already created. I have created a separate file call "Navbar.vue" where I'm using this route-link as the primary navigation menu. Following are the route links that i have created:

- Home
- About
- Movies
- Actors
- Profile

The output is attached below.

[image]

2. Now the issue is every link is working fine except "Movie", I'm unable to hover over it. But whenever I remove that the adjutant link shows the same problem. Following is the code of the router link:

```
   <div class="navLink col-3">
                      <router-link  class="link" to="/">Home</router-link>
                      <router-link class="link"  to="/about">About</router-link> 
                      <router-link class="link"  to="/movies">Movies</router-link> 
                      <router-link class="link"  to="/actors">Actors</router-link> 
                      <router-link class="link"  to="/profile">Profile</router-link> 
               </div>
```

**ROUTES REGISTRATION**

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    component:About,
  },
  {
    path: '/actors',
    name: 'Actors',
    component: Actors,
  },
  {
    path: '/movies',
    name: 'Movies',
    component: Movies,
  },
  {
    path: '/profile',
    name: 'Profile',
    component: Profile,
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes,
});
```

HTML CONSOLE OUTPUT
[image]
Can anyone guide me on what exactly I'm missing? PS The corresponding views of each route link are created and each route is registered successfully.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to VueJS router-link active style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46083220/how-to-vuejs-router-link-active-style)

Comment: Have you properly registered these routes in "const routes" in vue router? Could you show us those routes?

Comment: I have edited my Question ( added the route registration code ) please check :)

Comment: What does your browser console say? What is the html output in the browser? can you check and add a screenshot?

Comment: @frank i have added the HTML console output in question

Comment: @MuhammadKhan You have to use `const router = createRouter({
  linkExactActiveClass: 'active',
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes
})` The 'active' class will be added to your router link

Comment: @jebasuthan I have added the code but can you elaborate on what do you mean by adding an active class to the router? Like following 
                        <router-link class="active link"  to="/about">About</router-link>

Comment: @MuhammadKhan ya exactly you can see the html like `<a class="active link" to="/about">About</a>` then you can add style using css `a.link.active { background-color:'red' }`

Comment: @jebasuthan ok sure let me try. I hope this will work :)

Comment: @jebasuthan unfortunately the same issue again :(

Comment: @MuhammadKhan Let me share the working example

Comment: @MuhammadKhan can you check the updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Step 1:*** `HTML` template

```
 <template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="navLink col-3">
      <router-link class="link" to="/">Home</router-link>
      <router-link class="link" to="/about">About</router-link>
      <router-link class="link" to="/movies">Movies</router-link>
      <router-link class="link" to="/actors">Actors</router-link>
      <router-link class="link" to="/profile">Profile</router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

***Step 2:*** Create `router`

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "../components/Home.vue";
import About from "../components/About.vue";
import Actors from "../components/Actors.vue";
import Movies from "../components/Movies.vue";
import Profile from "../components/Profile.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    name: "About",
    component: About
  },
  {
    path: "/actors",
    name: "Actors",
    component: Actors
  },
  {
    path: "/movies",
    name: "Movies",
    component: Movies
  },
  {
    path: "/profile",
    name: "Profile",
    component: Profile
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  linkExactActiveClass: "active",
  routes
});

export default router;
```

***Step 3:*** Add `style` for active class

```
 <style>
.link {
  margin: 10px;
}
.link.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

[image]
[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-tdd-5li8s)

Comment: Greate thanks a mil tons dear it works :)

Comment: @MuhammadKhan Its my pleasure! Accept and give a thumbs up for the answer!