# Difference between active and exact active Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router

What is the difference between `router-link-active`/`nuxt-link-active` and `router-link-exact-active`/`nuxt-link-exact-active`. When `router-link-active` is applied?

Comment: No big difference between the Nuxt and Vue links, Nuxt uses the one from Vue mostly (probably add some small things regarding SSR). If you're using Nuxt, keep using the Nuxt link as a cohesive convention (having router link and Nuxt link at the same time would confuse your colleagues IMO). As for exact, I can't test right now on a machine but last time I checked it was related to the exact path. Example, `/biscuits/details` is an active path for `/biscuits` (because parent of the nested `details`) and the `exact` one is the whole thing `/biscuits/details`. Check Vue devtools, routes tab.

Comment: So it's basically `kinda contains` vs `strictly exact` as explained more in depth here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46085519/8816585

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46083220/how-to-vuejs-router-link-active-style